# Does TcpClient write method guarantees the data are delivered to server?

Tags: c#, sockets, stream, tcpclient

I have a separate thread on both client and server that are reading/writing data to/from a socket.

I am using synchronous TcpClient im (as suggested in documention):
https://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

When connection is closed .Read()/.Write() throws an exception. Does it mean that when .Write() method does not throw the data were delivered correctly to the other party or **do I need to implement custom ACK logic**?

I read documentation for both Socket and TcpClient class and none of them describe this case.

Comment: For future readers, please note that I changed the accepted answer to @CodeCaster as there are some valid points in the links he provided

Answer (score 13, accepted):

All that a returning `send()` call means (or any wrapper you use, like `Socket` or `TcpClient`) on a streaming, blocking internet socket is that the bytes are placed in the sending machine's buffer.

[MSDN `Socket.Send()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145160%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> A successful completion of the Send method means that the underlying system has had room to buffer your data for a network send.

And:

> The successful completion of a send does not indicate that the data was successfully delivered.

For .NET, the underlying implementation is WinSock2, documentation: [send()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740149%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> The successful completion of a send function does not indicate that the data was successfully delivered and received to the recipient. This function only indicates the data was successfully sent.

A call to `send()` returning does **not** mean the data was successfully delivered to the other side and read by the consuming application.

When data is not acknowledged in time, or when the other party sends a RST, the `Socket` (or whichever wrapper) will become in a faulted state, making the *next* `send()` or `recv()` fail.

So in order to answer your question:

> Does it mean that when .Write() method does not throw the data were delivered 
>   correctly to the other party or do I need to implement custom ACK logic?

No, it doesn't, and yes, you should - **if** it's important to your application that it knows another party has read that particular message.

This would for example be the case if a server-sent message indicates a state change of some sort on the client, which the client must apply to remain in sync. If the client doesn't acknowledge that message, the server cannot know for certain that the client has an up-to-date state.

In that case you could alter your protocol so that certain messages have a required response which the receiver must return. Do note that implementing an application protocol is surprisingly easy to do wrong. If you're inclined, you could implement having various protocol-dictated message flows using a [state machine](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/Stateless30AStateMachineLibraryForNETCore.aspx),
 for both the server and the client.

Of course there are other solutions to that problem, such as giving each state a unique identifier, which is verified with the server before attempting any operation involving that state, triggering the retry of the earlier failed synchronization.

See also [How to check the capacity of a TCP send buffer to ensure data delivery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8405686/how-to-check-the-capacity-of-a-tcp-send-buffer-to-ensure-data-delivery), [Finding out if a message over tcp was delivered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531207/finding-out-if-a-message-over-tcp-was-delivered), [C socket: does send wait for recv to end?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3578650/c-socket-does-send-wait-for-recv-to-end)

Comment: While true, TCPClient implements TCP protocol, that is responsible to ensure the data was sent and received by using acknowledgements. Same is true when using a socket that is using Tcp protocol type.

Comment: @Zohar that is not true. TcpClient is a wrapper around the Socket class which in turn is a wrapper around WinSock which implements Berkeley Sockets, who don't promise any such thing. The only thing `send()` does is **queue the bytes for sending**.

Comment: In that case, what's the point of calling the protocol Tcp if it's not actually TPC compliant?

Comment: Networks are messy, sockets are an abstraction. A few layers below your code TCP *is* implemented. It's called `TcpClient` because it does, in the end, use sockets who call system functions that implement TCP.

Comment: @CodeCaster, TcpClient is indeed a wrapper around Berkeley Sockets implementation. But Berkeley Sockets implement different protocols, (TCP, UDP, raw data etc). Your references to MSDN is for the general case of send(), but we are talking about specific case - TCP protocol. When Berkeley Socket is created specifically for TCP protocol, data delivery is guaranteed. Check Socket constructors here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.socket%28v=vs.110%29.aspx and you will see that you can specify specific protocol for the socket.

Comment: If TCP is implemented correctly, it's a built in feature that data is sure to arrive to it's destination, and that's what the OP wanted to know. I think most of the time we can trust the good people of the .Net development team to actually implement TCP protocol when using TCPClient and TCPListener...

Comment: @Denis I know how TCP works. I know you can create a TCP socket. The Berkeley Sockets API, as implemented through WinSock and used by .NET does _not_ link the TCP level to the API level. This means `send()` returns **before** the packets are acknowledged. See [Finding out if a message over tcp was delivered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531207/finding-out-if-a-message-over-tcp-was-delivered).

Comment: @CodeCaster, could you take a look at http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system/net/System/Net/Sockets/TCPClient.cs, line 222. I read the following:  ipv4Socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
Does the last parameter (ProtocolType.Tcp) not mean that the socket is created for the Tcp protocol on the API level?
Socket.cs constructor further traces to extern API WSASocket() call from ws2_32.dll library. Am I wrong that this creates Berkley Socket for the TCP protocol?

Comment: @Denis I have explained myself various times now. Please link to documentation where it says _"A `send()` call on a blocking TCP socket returning means the data was ACK'ed by the client"_, as that is OP's question. If `send()` returns, the kernel has accepted the buffer and will try to deliver it. That's all `send()` does. "Send" in socket terminology means "placed in the outgoing buffer".

Comment: @CodeCaster, thank you for mutliple explanations, though I'm still in a disagreement with you, and believe that the documentation you are referencing is written for the general case, which includes the use of sockets created for various other non-tcp protocols that do not guarantee delivery indeed. Will be happy to prove my point by continuing this discussion elsewhere, if you would like

Comment: Computer A sends data to computer B. Computer B receives the data, but before it becomes able to return ACK message, an error occurs, and it couldn't have been sent back to Computer A. Question is whether Computer B has received the message or not? In reality, yes it has received, but Computer A would think that because it hasn't received any ACK, it wasn't received. As the OP asks, would you rely on this if you want to build a reliable system?

Answer (score 6):

@CodeCaster's answer is correct and highlights the .NET documentation specifying the behavior of .Write().  Here is some complete test code to prove that he is right and the other answers saying things like "TCP guarantees message delivery" are unambiguously wrong:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace TestEvents
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Server: Start listening for incoming connections
            const int PORT = 4411;
            var listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, PORT);
            listener.Start();

            // Client: Connect to listener
            var client = new TcpClient();
            client.Connect(IPAddress.Loopback, PORT);

            // Server: Accept incoming connection from client
            TcpClient server = listener.AcceptTcpClient();

            // Server: Send a message back to client to prove we're connected
            const string msg = "We are now connected";
            NetworkStream serverStream = server.GetStream();
            serverStream.Write(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msg), 0, msg.Length);

            // Client: Receive message from server to prove we're connected
            var buffer = new byte[1024];
            NetworkStream clientStream = client.GetStream();
            int n = clientStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            Console.WriteLine("Received message from server: " + ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, n));

            // Client: Close connection and wait a little to make sure we won't ACK any more of server's messages
            Console.WriteLine("Client is closing connection");
            clientStream.Dispose();
            client.Close();
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            Console.WriteLine("Client has closed his end of the connection");

            // Server: Send a message to client that client could not possibly receive
            serverStream.Write(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msg), 0, msg.Length);
            Console.WriteLine(".Write has completed on the server side even though the client will never receive the message.  server.Client.Connected=" + server.Client.Connected);

            // Let the user see the results
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

The thing to note is that execution proceeds normally all the way through the program and serverStream has no indication that the second .Write was not successful.  This is despite the fact there is no way that second message can ever be delivered to its recipient.  For a more detailed look at what's going on, you can replace IPAddress.Loopback with a longer route to your computer (like, have your router route port 4411 to your development computer and use the externally-visible IP address of your modem) and monitor that port in Wireshark.  Here's what the output looks like:

[image: Wireshark screen capture of port activity]

Port 51380 is a randomly-chosen port representing the client TcpClient in the code above.  There are double packets because this setup uses NAT on my router.  So, the first SYN packet is my computer -> my external IP.  The second SYN packet is my router -> my computer.  The first PSH packet is the first serverStream.Write.  The second PSH packet is the second serverStream.Write.

One might claim that the client does ACK at the TCP level with the RST packet, but 1) this is irrelevant to the use of TcpClient since that would mean TcpClient is ACKing with a closed connection and 2) consider what happens when the connection is completely disabled in the next paragraph.

If I comment out the lines that dispose the stream and close the client, and instead disconnect from my wireless network during the Thread.Sleep, the console prints the same output and I get this from Wireshark:

[image: Wireshark activity when wireless is disconnected]

Basically, .Write returns without Exception even though no PSH packet was even dispatched, let alone had received an ACK.

If I repeat the process above but disable my wireless card instead of just disconnecting, THEN the second .Write throws an Exception.

Bottom line, @CodeCaster's answer is unambiguously correct on all levels and more than one of the other answers here are incorrect.

Comment: Am getting "Unable to read data from the transport connection" error at serverStream.Write(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msg), 0, msg.Length) if am closing the Client and connecting it again halfway (my client is a python application).  If c# application is also restarted, it works. Again if I close the client and connect it again, error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

TcpClient uses TCP protocol which itself guarantees data delivery. If the data is not delivered, you will get an exception. If no exception is thrown - the data has been delivered.

Please see the description of the TCP protocol here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol

Every time the data is sent, the sending computer waits for the acknowledgement packet to arrive, and if it has not arrived, it will re-try the send until it is either successful, timed out, or permanent network failure has been detected (for example, cable disconnect). In the latter two cases an exception will be thrown

Therefore, TCP offeres *guaranteed* data delivery in the sense that you *always* know whether the destination received your data or not

So, to answer your question, you do NOT need to implement custom ACK logic when using TcpClient, as it will be redundant

Comment: But it's worth bearing in mind that the sending of packets over the network is *not* necessarily related 1-1 with calls of `Write` at the sending side nor calls of `Read` at the receiving side. There are buffers in between

Comment: True, you can send 100 bytes, but the destination will receive them in 2 chunks of 70+30 or any other way. However, the order of bytes is guaranteed to be preserved

Comment: This answer is unambiguously incorrect; see my answer below.

Answer (score -1):

Guarantee is never possible. What you can know is that data has left your computer for delivery to other side in the order of data was sent.

If you want a very reliable system, you should implement acknowledgement logic by yourself based on your needs.

Comment: Wrong. TCP protocol ensures a reliable data transfer. form wikipedia: *TCP provides reliable, ordered, and error-checked delivery of a stream of octets between applications running on hosts communicating over an IP network.*

Comment: IMHO this is not quite correct, please check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol
TCP itself implements ACK logic and if the data has left the sending computer, but the acknowledgement packet has not been received by the sending computer, TCP protocol will be re-trying sends until one of the three happens (success, timeout ,permanent network failure)

Answer (score -2):

I agree with Denis.

From the documentation (and my experience): this method will block until all bytes were written or throw an exception on error (such as disconnect). If the method returns you are guaranteed that the bytes were delivered and read by the other ***side on the TCP level***.

Vojtech - I think you missed the documentation since you need to look at the Stream you're using.

See: [MSDN NetworkStream.Write method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.write%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), in the remarks section:

> The Write method blocks until the requested number of bytes is sent or a SocketException is thrown.

Notes

- Assuring that the message was actually read properly by the listening application is another issue and the framework cannot guarantee this.
- In async methods (such as BeginWrite or WriteAsync) it's a different ballgame since the method returns immediately and the mechanism to assure completion is different (EndWrite or task completion paired with a code).

Comment: So the bottom line is to implement custom ACK logic anyway... Right?

Comment: _"f the method returns you are guaranteed that the bytes were delivered and read by the other side"_ - no, it doesn't.

Comment: Custom ACK logic is most probably redundant and should not be implemented. I would only implement a request/response idiom for specific messages.

Comment: CodeCaster - what is guaranteed? The placement of the message on the send buffer and only that?

Comment: @YosefO as far as I can find documentation, yes, it does.

Comment: This is incorrect: "If the method returns you are guaranteed that the bytes were delivered and read by the other side on the TCP level" -- see my answer for more details.