# Is is possible to know if data was buffered when a TCP connection fails on Linux?

Tags: sockets, tcp, network-programming

When you call `send` on a socket, data buffers in the kernel and you get a non-error return. The kernel implementation gets busy acking and windowing to get all your data to the other end.

If a Pekinese Terrier bites through a wire, the connection will close, leaving some data unsent. Is there any way to find out, upon getting the error indicating the close, that this is the case? Eventually a mechanism on Linux, Windows, and OS/X is desirable, but it doesn't have to be the *same* mechanism.

Someone in a comment wondered: why?

Consider a system that can already recover from entire crashes of a node, but was built with the assumption that 'TCP connections are forever' (which they are not, necessarily, on AWS). So, if a TCP connection closes, there are only two possibilities: the other end has crashed, and we've got a solution for that, or it's still up. If it's still up, it got as much data as TCP delivered before the socket closed. (I realize this is not necessarily a valid assumption.) Since the TCP protocol is already doing all this ack book-keeping in the kernel, it seems a shame to replicate it in user space to keep track of how much got from one end to the other.

Comment: Not that  I'm aware of. The connection gets reset and all buffered data is discarded.

Comment: There's a greater question looming: what would you want that for? An obvious intent is to know whether the receiver had a chance to get it, but there's so many ways it could fail event after it was "sent out", between the bit wires you mentioned to the receiving end's TCP stack, to the application on the other end, that in the end it seems like a pointless endeavor. To me at least.

Comment: @JB. The connection will at least have the last ACKed seqnr present somewhere in its internal structure. But I don't think this is accessible, at least not for a userspace process, and certainly not after a connection close. (the good news is that a broken cable does not cause a connection close, just a timeout, eventually)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've stumbled across this problem myself, and so have others (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1531207/3199595) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30703500/3199595)).

Since TCP is buffered and as it abstracts away the nitty gritty details of re-transmissions, acks and the like, there is no clean way of making sure at the application layer that your data was delivered.

Moreover, and this is key, even if it did provide you with some sort of confirmation that the data was delivered, it could only confirm delivery to the TCP buffer on the other end. You'd still be left with the question of whether that data was actually processed by the actual application. After all, it could be that a second Pekinese Terrier could have suddenly killed the application you're talking to or caused it to hang so it can't read the data from its TCP buffer.

If you need application layer acknowledgment of data delivery (and/or processing), you need an application layer mechanism for doing so by way of application layer acknowledgments.