# Check if NamedPipeClientStream write is successful

Tags: c#, named-pipes

Basically the title... I'd like to have same feedback on weather `NamedPipeServerStream` object successfully received a value. This is the starting code:

```
static void Main(string[] args){
  Console.WriteLine("Client running!");

  NamedPipeClientStream npc = new NamedPipeClientStream("somename");
  npc.Connect();

  // npc.WriteTimeout = 1000; does not work, says it is not supported for this stream
  byte[] message = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Message");
  npc.Write(message);

  int response = npc.ReadByte();
  Console.WriteLine("response; "+response);

}
```

I've implemented a small echo message from the NamedPipeServerStream on every read. I imagine I could add some async timeout to check if npc.ReadByte(); did return a value in lets say 200ms. Similar to how TCP packets are ACKed.

Is there a better way of inspecting if `namedPipeClientStream.Write()` was successful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'd like to have same feedback on weather NamedPipeServerStream object successfully received a value

The only way to know for sure that the data you sent was received and successfully processed by the client at the remote endpoint, is for your own application protocol to include such acknowledgements.

As a general rule, you can *assume* that if your send operations are completing successfully, the connection remains viable and the remote endpoint is getting the data. If something happens to the connection, you'll eventually get an error while sending data.

However, this assumption only goes so far. Network I/O is buffered, usually at several levels. Any of your send operations almost certainly involve doing nothing more than placing the data in a local buffer for the network layer. The method call for the operation will return as soon as the data has been buffered, without regard for whether the remote endpoint has received it (and in fact, almost never will have by the time your call returns).

So if and when such a call throws an exception or otherwise reports an error, it's entirely possible that some of the previously sent data has also been lost in transit.

How best to address this possibility depends on what you're trying to do. But in general, you should not worry about it at all. It will typically not matter if a specific transmission has been received. As long as you can continue transmitting without error, the connection is fine, and asking for acknowledgement is just unnecessary overhead.

If you want to handle the case where an error occurs, invalidating the connection, forcing you to retry, and you want to make the broader operation resumable (e.g. you're streaming some data to the remote endpoint and want to ensure all of the data has been received, without having to resend data that has already been received), then you should build into your application protocol the ability to resume, where on reconnecting the remote endpoint reports the number of bytes it's received so far, or the most recent message ID, or whatever it is your application protocol would need to understand where it needs to start sending again.

See also this very closely-related question (arguably maybe even an actual duplicate…though it doesn't mention named pipes specifically, pretty much all network I/O will involve similar issues):
[Does TcpClient write method guarantees the data are delivered to server?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30703500)

There's a good answer there, as well as links to even more useful Q&A in that answer.